# If $\Re(f)=\Re(g)$ on the boundary of $D$ then the equality is also true on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f,g$ be holomorphic on a bounded domain $D$ and continuous on
> $\overline{D}$. Assume that $\Re(f)=\Re(g)\forall z\in\partial D$.
> Prove that $\Re (f-g)=0$.

My attempt
Consider $h=f-g$. Clearly $h$ is holomorphic on $D$, continuous on $\overline{D}$.
If $h$ is constant, then we finish.
If $h$ is non-constant. According to Maximum modulus principle, for all $z\in\overline{D}$, we have $$|h(z)|\leq|h(z_0)|\quad (\text{ for some }z_0\in\partial D).$$
which also means that $$\sqrt{\Re^2(f(z)-g(z))+\Im^2(f(z)-g(z))}\leq\sqrt{\Im^2(f(z_0)-g(z_0))}$$
Hence we obtain the following inequality $$\Re^2(f(z)-g(z))+\Im^2(f(z)-g(z))\leq\Im^2(f(z_0)-g(z_0))^2\quad\forall z\in\overline{D}.$$
I'm stuck at here. Could someone help me to continue or another way to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the real part of a holomorphic function $f$, it is usually helpful to consider $\exp(f)$. So let us consider a function
$$h(z)=\exp(f(z)-g(z)) $$
on $\overline{D}$. Then $|h(z)|=1$ on $\partial D$ and hence the maximum modulus principle, applied to both $h$ and $1/h$, shows that $|h|=1$ everywhere on $D$. Thus $f$ and $g$ have the same real part.

Answer (score 3):

Since $h = f-g$ is holomorphic the real-part $\Re(h)$ is harmonic. So, it attains its maximum and minimum on the boundary. But $\Re(h) = 0$ on $\partial D$, so $\Re(f-g) = 0$ on the whole $D$.